# Difference between let and var inside setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I know the difference between let and var. let is block scope and var is functional scope.

```
for(var i=0; i< 3; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(i);
    }, 10);
}

output : 3
         3
         3
```

I know how above code snippet is working(`console.log(i)` is executing at that time when value of i is 3, because scope of i is global).

**But**

```
for(let i=0; i< 3; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(i);
    }, 10);
}

output : 1
         2
         3
```

the above code snippet confusing me. according to me it should throw Reference Error(because the time when `console.log(i)` execute, will look the value of i in global scope not in local scope, and i is not declare/defined in global. so it should give reference error.)

Anyone who can explain how 2nd for loop working on Runtime ?

Comment: Closure closes over the new instance of i for each iteration when using let.

Comment: If a `Reference Error` would be thrown, then no kind of closure would work. Neither the one for the function scope `var`, nor the one for the `let`.

Comment: Go and read this [article](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html) when you have time. It explains scoping, hoisting etc. really well.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `let` in this context, a new binding/scope is created at each iteration. If you want to achieve a similar behavior in ES5 with `var`, you have to use an IIFE:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  (function (i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log(i);
    }, 10);
  })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The second example (using `let`) works because a function will close over all variables that are in scope when it is declared. Each iteration of the for loop a new variable is being created with `let`, the function in the timeout closes over the variable and keeps a referance. When the function is dereferenced after the timeout, so are its closure variables.

See [How do JavaScript closures work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/3877726) for more information on function closure.

Answer (score 4):

This is the magic of closure. In side your loop

```
for(let i=0; i< 3; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(i);
    }, 10);
}
```

you are declaring a function

```
function(){
  console.log(i);
}
```

Additionally, the loop itself declares a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block)

```
for(let i=0; i< 3; i++){
  // this is a block scope because it is contained in 
  // braces
}
```

Variables defined with `let` are block scoped.

Because of [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), the function you declare inside the loop has access to all the variables declared in its scope *and its parents scopes* until it is garbage collected.

> A closure is the combination of a function and the lexical environment
>   within which that function was declared. This environment consists of
>   any local variables that were in-scope at the time that the closure
>   was created.

The variable `i` is *in-scope* when the functions used by `setTimeout` are created. The `i` referred to is a different instance of `i` for each iteration of the loop.

The function exists until the interval you declared passes. That is why each of the 3 functions declared in your loop print the value of `i`; *it was declared in the containing scope and remains available to the function*.