# Do we need variable declaration using `for..of` / `for..in` loops

Tags: javascript, node.js

I see examples like this online:

```
const roles = [];

for (i of roles) {
  roleObj[roles[i].key] = true;
}
```

do we need not declare the variable i, like so?

```
for (let i of roles) {
  roleObj[roles[i].key] = true;
}
```

tons of articles are promoting the first example, which seems pretty dumb to me:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: Well `i` would be global so yes it is best practice to declare it

Comment: In `strict` mode, using a variable without declaring it is an error and, for very good reason, because creating an accidental or implicit global is very easy to make a messy, hard to find bug, particular when there is async code involved.  So, NEVER use a variable without declaring it.  To be safe, put all your code in `strict` mode.  Some ES6 things are automatically strict mode such as methods on a class declaration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't absolutely need to, but it's **highly** recommended to do so and in fact to use `let`. Note that using `let i` in this case will actually function differently than if you just did `for (i` or `for (var i`.

As an example:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  process.nextTick(() => console.log(i));
}
// print 0..9

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  process.nextTick(() => console.log(i));
}
// prints 10 ten times.
```

Also note that with `let` you would *not* be able to use `i` after the loop, but you could with `var`, and if you do not use `var` the variable will be in the global scope so it would work differently if it were inside of a function:

```
function gl() {
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {}
  for (var j = 0; i < 10; i++) {}
  for (let x = 0; i < 10; i++) {}
  console.log(i, j) // prints 10, 10
  console.log(x) // runtime error
}
gl();
console.log(i) // prints 10
console.log(j) // runtime error
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments, accessing variables without declarations is not allowed in strict mode.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44606868/difference-between-let-and-var-inside-settimeout

Comment: @BhojendraNepal - There are hundreds of articles on `let` vs. `var`.  Please read ten of them and then file your own question is there's still something you don't understand.  We are way more effective if you use us for things that can't easily be found on Google.

Comment: You should mention `strict` mode and mention ES6 code that is automatically in `strict` mode where it IS required to declare it first.